# Bitmap sometimes is null

Tags: android, bitmap, null

I have a problem. See, please, my code.

```
if(savedInstanceState==null){
        mImagePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inMutable=true;

                ExifInterface exif;
                try {
                    exif = new ExifInterface(new File(mImagePath).getAbsolutePath());
                    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                    int rotate = 0;

                    switch (orientation) {
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                            rotate = 270;
                            break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                            rotate = 180;
                            break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                            rotate = 90;
                            break;
                    }

                    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImagePath,options);

                    if(rotatedBitmap==null){
                        Answers.getInstance().logCustom(new CustomEvent("Null 1"));
                        // The first place where sometimes bitmap is null
                    }


                    assert rotatedBitmap != null;
                    int width = rotatedBitmap.getWidth();
                    int height = rotatedBitmap.getHeight();


                    if (Math.max(width,height)>MAX_LENGTH_OF_IMAGE){
                        // if widht or height >1500 px then i resize the image
                        float factor = MAX_LENGTH_OF_IMAGE/Math.max(width,height);
                        width=(int)(width*factor);
                        height=(int)(height*factor);
                        mOriginalBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rotatedBitmap,width,height,true);
                        rotatedBitmap.recycle();
                    } else
                        mOriginalBitmap=rotatedBitmap;

                    if(rotate!=0){
                        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                        matrix.postRotate(rotate);
                        rotattedBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(mOriginalBitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
                        mOriginalBitmap.recycle();
                        mOriginalBitmap=rotattedBitmap;
                    }
                    if(mOriginalBitmap==null){
                        Answers.getInstance().logCustom(new CustomEvent("Null 187"));
                        //I didn't receive this message
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    finish();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(mOriginalBitmap==null){
                    Answers.getInstance().logCustom(new CustomEvent("Null 206"));
                    // The second place where bitmap sometimes is null
                }
                mCurrentBitmap=mOriginalBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        onCreated();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Sometimes the bitmap is null (in two places). This error occurs in 6-7 users out of 1000.

I can always check if the bitmap is null and don't perform operations with this bitmap (bitmap.copy, bitmap.getwidth and others), but what should I do to always load a bitmap?

Comment: What does `mImagePath` Contains? Whats the file  size ?  Is there an OOM error ?

Comment: @ADM, mImagePath contains Path at the image file. No, it isn't an OOM error. At the first check, the bitmap is not null, but at the second, sometimes, is null

Comment: if there is an error in ur try, it will be catched and the code continues, in this case, this line: mOriginalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImagePath,options); did not execute and the second if check outside the try and catch checks the mOriginalBitmap that is not set and recognizes that its null.

Comment: That maybe because Some `IOException` has occured during decoding  . So first `if(mOriginalBitmap==null)` will be skipped. print the stack trace from exception and check logs

Comment: @sagat , you're right, but in the catch block is the finish() command.

Comment: and what is happening in that finish() function?

Comment: @sagat I understood. Activity is closed, but the thread continues to work. Yes?

Comment: @sagat , I have one more question. After second "if", i have this code

File file = new File(mImagePath);                if(file.getParentFile().equals(getExternalFilesDir(DIRECTORY_PICTURES)))
    file.delete();
if(mOriginalBitmap==null){
    Answers.getInstance().logCustom(new CustomEvent("Null 214"));
}

Now , if in the second "if" the bitmap is not null then sometimes in the third "if" bitmap is null.

Comment: To really help you I would recommend to show us the whole code, that you wrote. Otherwise we wont get the context. Please edit your question, so that we can see the whole code, that is causing trouble. Best regards!

Comment: @sagat, hello!
I updated the post and wrote the main code. I also changed the essence of the question.

Comment: Thx a lot. Did u check the filepath? with debuggin? When you try to decode the file? Set a breakpoint here --> Bitmap rotatedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImagePath,options); And check what happens!

Comment: @sagat thanks, but i never got this error. On my devices everything works as it should.

Comment: @VladAdrian Okay, if u can not reproduce the error this is hard to guess. To Prevent getting null, maybe wrap the logic with --> if(mImagePath != null) {do something...}. Maybe you can check for a pattern in the imageFilePath that you need or are looking for. Best regards

Comment: @sagat , A couple of times I sent the path when the bitmap was null. Here, for example, one path that I received /storage/2B41-1DFA/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20180304_141707539HDR.jpg